# how to resolve when MPMediaItem assetURL is nil?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm working on code that looks at the user's videos and passes them along to AVPlayer by way of an AVPlayerItem which takes a URL.

To get all the videos on an iOS device, you can do:

```
let videoNumber = MPMediaType.anyVideo.rawValue
let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate.init(value: videoNumber, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType)
let query = MPMediaQuery.init()
query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)

if let items = query.items
{
    mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: items)

    // -1 would indicate an error condition
    print("number of items in collection is \(mediaCollection?.count ?? -1)")
}
```

When you select the MPMediaItem you want to use from the `items` array, there should be an `assetURL` to go with it.

Trouble is, on my device, all of my `assetURL` properties are NULL.  Coincidentally, while `hasProtectedAsset` for each of these items is `false`, `isCloudItem` for each of these items is `true`.

How can I come up with a valid `assetURL` that I can pass along to any media player?  It feels somewhat bogus that developers can't get proper references & access to media in a user's iPod library.

Comment: Have you found any solution for the above issue?

Comment: No, @AbilashBNair. Apple's DTS says it's a feature enhancement that I should request through https://bugreporter.apple.com ... In the meantime, you should up vote this question to increase its visibility and maybe attract a useful answer from somebody.