# MPMediaPickerController-> MPmediaitem -> NSDATA (xamarin, c#, ios)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

```
async void SoundPickingMedia(object sender, ItemsPickedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.MediaItemCollection.Items != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in args.MediaItemCollection.Items)
        {
            NSError error;
            NSUrl url = item.AssetURL;
            NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(url, 0, out error);
            Stream stream = data.AsStream();
         }
    }
}
```

NSUrl url -> null

how to use AVAssetExportSession from xamarin c#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402143/how-to-resolve-when-mpmediaitem-asseturl-is-nil

Comment: Did you check [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVAssetExportSession/)?

Comment: I've seen it, but it does not help at this stage.